# Inline EnsureLoaded() with LINQ and EntityFramework

Tags: c#, xml, linq, entity-framework

I'm generating some XML with the following code, however the system I'm working on uses manual loading instead of lazy loading within the EntityFramework.  So in effect, I have to call EnsureLoaded() to explicitly say what elements need loading.  The problem is calling EnsureLoaded() withing deeply nested fields.  Here is my code;

```
public partial class Test
{
    public XElement ReturnDetails()
    {
        Test.DriverReference.EnsureLoaded();

        return new XElement("Test",
            new XAttribute("CarNum", CarNum),
            new XAttribute("Make", Make ?? string.Empty),
            new XAttribute("Model", Model ?? string.Empty),
            new XAttribute("Colour", Colour ?? string.Empty),
            new XElement("Drivers",
            from driver in Drivers
            select new XElement("Driver",
                new XAttribute("DriverNum", driver.DriverNum),
                new XAttribute("Notes", driver.Notes),
                new XElement("Routes"),
                from route in driver.Routes
                select new XElement("Route",
                    new XAttribute("Name", route.Name),
                    new XAttribute("Notes", route.Notes)
                ))));
    }
}
```

The problem is getting the value of Driver, and keep getting NullReferenceExceptions when going beyond three level of Entity hierarchies.  What I want to do is the following;

```
public partial class Test
{
    public XElement ReturnDetails()
    {
        Test.DriverReference.EnsureLoaded();

        return new XElement("Test",
            new XAttribute("CarNum", CarNum),
            new XAttribute("Make", Make ?? string.Empty),
            new XAttribute("Model", Model ?? string.Empty),
            new XAttribute("Colour", Colour ?? string.Empty),
            new XElement("Drivers",
            from driver in Drivers.EnsureLoaded() *****
            select new XElement("Driver",
                new XAttribute("DriverNum", driver.DriverNum),
                new XAttribute("Notes", driver.Notes),
                new XElement("Routes"),
                from route in driver.Routes.EnsureLoaded() *****
                select new XElement("Route",
                    new XAttribute("Notes", route.Notes),
                    new XAttribute("Name", route.Name)
                ))));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried .Include? e.g. if Drivers is a top level ObjectSet you need to call .EnsureLoaded before you start building your Xml but for routes you can try from route in `driver.Include("Routes")`

Comment: I have but I get the error; System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Include(bool, bool, System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference>)' is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: Strange as it's a public partial class.  Any ideas?